# PHP associative array access

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array like below with, the actual array is much larger. This is just part of it. I want to access **only** the elements that have **"[equipmentType] => WARRANTY"** in it. In this case the element number is [39] but that element number changes, it's not always [39].

I know I can access $arrayName["equipment"]["39"]["name"] for example but how do I access it when it's not [39]?

In this particular example, there are 44 elements as you can see with the [equipmentCount] value.

I apologize if I'm not explaining this well.

```
Array
(
    [equipment] => Array
    (

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20073207920
                [name] => Mobile Connectivity
                [equipmentType] => OTHER
                [availability] => STANDARD
                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Bluetooth
                                [value] => Bluetooth
                            )

                    )

            )

        [39] => Array
            (
                [id] => 200732343
                [name] => Rust, 5 Years,  /U Miles
                [equipmentType] => WARRANTY
                [availability] => STANDARD
                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Warranty End Date
                                [value] => 09-Sep-2099
                            )
                    )

            )

    )

    [equipmentCount] => 44
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use a foreach loop to loop over that particular subArray and then access the name index in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but how do I do that when the key [39] can be different? Associate arrays give me a headache ;-)

Comment: Just do `foreach($variableName as $key => $name){echo "$key => $name <br />";}` and you will see what you iterate over. Then I'm sure you will get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, maybe that's what you want:

```
array_filter($array['equipment'], function($equip){
        return array_search('WARRANTY', $equip);
})
```

Comment: Thank You! I was looking at array_filter but wasn't quite sure how to use it. Now I can just loop through the sub array as needed.